# Якщо "квиток", то чому "безбілетний"?

Tags: значення-слів, spelling

Сайт [Мова. ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/bilet-i-kvitok) дає такі пояснення вживання слів *квиток* та *білет*:

**Білет**

1. Картка з питаннями для тих, хто складає іспит або залік (екзаменаційний білет).
2. Грошовий документ (кредитний, банківський).

**Квиток**

1. Документ, який засвідчує належність до організації (партійний, журналістський).
2. Куплена картка, що дає право проїзду на транспорті, відвідання музею тощо (трамвайний, залізничний).

Проте людину, що не має квитка на проїзд, називають [безбілетною](http://sum.in.ua/s/bezbiletnyj), *безквитковий* визначають як `розм.`:

1. заст. Який не має паспорта, документа на проживання де-небудь; безпаспортний. Безбілетні бурлаки.
2. розм. Який не має квитка (на проїзд і т. ін.); безквитковий. Безбілетний пасажир.

За прямим посиланням [БЕЗКВИТКО́ВИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/bezkvytkovyj) маємо:

> БЕЗКВИТКО́ВИЙ, а, е. Без квитка.

ЗМІ теж часто використовують ["безбілетний пасажир"](https://www.google.com.ua/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=1d62WNLYEabs8weDy67QDg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%80&*).

Чому така невідповідність і який варіант є коректним?

Comment: Звертаюся до тих, хто мінусує це запитання. Взагалі, автор запитання має право помилятися. Він провів власне дослідження і прийшов до деякого (можливо, помилкового) висновку. Ми тут для того і зібралися, щоб встановити істину. Напишіть відповідь з поясненням і посиланнями на поважні джерела. А мінусувати запитання треба тоді, коли видно, що автор не провів власної роботи та/або нечітко сформулював проблему (або написав offtopic). У даному випадку, **запитання — хороше**. Почитайте tooltip, який з'являється, коли поставити мишку над кнопками голосування.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### «Білет» і «квиток»

[Білет](http://sum.in.ua/s/bilet) теж мав (раніше?) значення:

> 1. Те саме, що [квиток](http://sum.in.ua/s/kvytok).

Хоча в [сучаснішому словнику](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4350&page=162) воно вже позначене як *заст[аріле]*:

> 1. *<sub>заст.</sub>* Те саме, що *квито́к 1*.
>
>    - [Юркевич:] У мене є ще білет моєї екскурсії – я ще поїду (І. Кочерга);
>    - За ворітьми у дворі стояв столик, на йому [ньому] свічка, якась шабатурка з білетами (В. Винниченко).

Тобто «Мова. ДНК нації» права у тому, що «картка, що дає право користуватися чим-небудь, входити куди-небудь, брати участь у чомусь» вже **не є одним із основних значень** слова «білет» — але, на мою думку, **занадто жорстка**, стверджуючи, наче це слово не можна вживати в цьому сенсі взагалі. Просто, коли Ви використовуватимете це слово в побуті, то про Вас можуть подумати, що Ви погано знаєте українську лексику, а не що Ви хизуєтеся ерудицією / знанням архаїзмів.

### «Безбілетний» і «безквитковий»

Ви якось невірно інтерпретуєте [статтю «безбілетний» у СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/bezbiletnyj). Там **не сказано**, що «безквитковий» розмовне, навпаки, там сказано, що (у значенні «без проїздного документа») **саме «безбілетний» розмовне** (а в значенні «без інших документів» — архаїзм; тобто воно не рекомендоване до вжитку в будь-якому значенні навіть у СУМ-11). А «безквитковий» — дозволене [навіть у СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/bezkvytkovyj).

СУМ-20 лише підтримує погляд СУМ-11 на ці слова:

- «[Безбілетний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=2960&page=123)» — застаріле (про ідентифікаційні документи) та розмовне (про проїзні документи).
- «[Безквитковий](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=3238&page=131)»:

  > 1. Який не має квитка.
  >
  >    - У поїзді старший кондуктор перевіряє квитки. Безквитковий пасажир сховався під лавку (із журн.).
  > 2. Який здійснюється без квитка.
  >
  >    - Люди ці були покарані за всілякі вчинки – за намагання вкрасти якусь консервну бляшанку з німецьких складів, за безквитковий проїзд залізницею (А. Хижняк).