# Як перекласти з російської "безбилетник"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як правильно позначити людину, що користується громадським транспортом без квитка? Деколи зустрічаю "безбілетник", але це явний варваризм, бо використовує як корінь рос. "билет". З прикметником проблем немає, всюди в траспорті маємо "Штраф за безквитковий проїзд", а ось з іменником ситуація незрозуміла.

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/745/

Comment: Розмовне *[безбілетник](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=184426&page=123)* в українській мові є (як розмовне *[безбілетний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=2960&page=131)* і застаріле *[білет](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4350&page=162)* в першому значенні). Але, звісно, хотілося б знайти якийсь літературний варіант.

Answer (score 4):

1. «Заєць»
2. Пасажир без квитку
3. Безквитко
4. Безквитчик
5. Безквитковик

Пояснення:
П1. У переносному сенсі, але відоме та вживане
П2. Не з одного слова, але правильно
П3-5. Це невживані варіанти і ніхто так не каже. Але слова не зайняті іншими значеннями — може, колись і так і казатимуть.

Виправлення: як справедливо зазначено в коментарях, правильніше буде «пасажир без квитка».

Доповнення: як справедливо зазначено в коментарях — як без хати безхатченко, так без квитка безквитченко — і це ще один невживаний варіант.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, завжди додавайте до ваших відповідей посилання на поважні джерела. Відповіді, які не містять таких посилань, лише запрошують до спростувань і, як результат, дуже рідко виявляються корисними.

Comment: Джерел немає, це моя відповідь.

Comment: Ну прям як "безхатченко" напрошується тоді "безквитченко" :D Але джерел і справді в вашій відповіді бракує.

Comment: Якби були б джерела, то, можливо, і запитання б не було.

Answer (score 0):

Гадаю можливі такі варіанти перекладу:

1. [Безбілетник](https://classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-russian-ukrainian-bigruuk-term-5160.htm) ([розмовний](http://www.unlimited-translate.org/uk/dictionaries/russian-to-ukrainian/translate/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA.htm) варіант).
2. [Заєць](https://ru.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA).
3. Пасажир без квитка (використовуємо описовий переклад).
4. Безквитковий пасажир (див. значення слова "[заєць](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D1%86%D1%8C)" в СУМі).

А також інколи ми можемо замінити це слово якимось іншим, якщо це припустимо:

**Оригінал**:

> Например, когда в районе Алис-Спрингса было нашествие диких кроликов,
>   проводники тайком запустили на поезд этих «безбилетников».

**Переклад**:

> Одного разу, коли в районі Аліс-Спрінгса розвелося багато кроликів,
>   вони нишком пронесли цих тварин на поїзд.